# How to Place my JavaFX Graph into a JFrame?

Tags: java, javafx

***Hello, I'm new in this Group. I am wondering if it is possible to add my JavaFX Graph inside my JFrame.***
**Here's my JFrame Looks Like and I want to Put my Graph Inside of it**
[image]

> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFyod.png`

**And Here's my Graph**
[image]

> `https://i.stack.imgur.com/koH7K.png`

**And Here's my Codes:**

> `https://pastebin.com/iwXZ0XR4`

Comment: Post a [mcve] not some off-site links

Comment: Next time, please add code to the post instead of making us dig through images and pastebin. Also, your question isn't exactly clear - are you looking to have the graph generated inside of the JFrame or just have the one pictured added?

Comment: sorry about that, the editor displays a lot of errors and tell me that I have to do it that way so I just followed. 

Yeahh I want to Generate a Graph inside of the JFrame using JavaFX

Comment: Use a [`javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put JavaFX in JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432629/how-to-put-javafx-in-jpanel)

Comment: @Slaw can you expand your info sir?, I don't really know what to do. Thanks sir

Comment: Take a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/jtable-barchart.htm#CHDBHIJJ) linked in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435001/6395627) to the linked question.